# Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application - Groovy .save()

Tags: database, grails, groovy

I have tried to succeed to save data to database by using GORM .save() method but it keeps giving me an "**outside of a Grails application**" error.

[image: ERROR PAGE]

My **domain class**

```
package com.example.ulu

import grails.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
class User {

    static String userName
    static String password
    static String fullName


    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

**Controller page**

```
package com.example.ulu

import java.sql.Connection
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import grails.util.Environment;
import java.sql.SQLClientInfoException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import org.springframework.http.*
import org.h2.command.ddl.CreateUser;
import org.h2.engine.DbObject;
import org.slf4j.*
import gorm.recipes.*
import com.example.ulu.User;
import com.mysql.jdbc.*
import groovy.sql.Sql
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import grails.converters.JSON

class UserController{   


    def index() { 

        redirect(action:"login")

    }

    def register = {}


    def registeruser = { 

            def b = new User(fullName:params.fullName, userName:params.userName, password:params.password)
            b.save()            
            render (b as JSON)

    }

}
```

**DataSource** page

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "root"
    password = ""
    //dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
        compile "javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final"
        compile "org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.5"
        compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5"
        runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final"

    }

    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:8.0.22" // or ":tomcat:8.0.20"

        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.14"

        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    }
```

**Register.gsp**

```
<g:form method="POST" url="[action:'registeruser',controller:'user']">
            <fieldset class="form">
                <div
                    class="fieldcontation ${hasErrors(model: flash?.userInstance, field: 'fullName', 'error')}">
                    <label for="fullName"> <g:message
                            code="endUser.fullName.label" default="Full Name" />
                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="fullName" value="${userInstance?.fullName}" />
                </div>
                <div
                    class="fieldcontation ${hasErrors(model: flash?.userInstance, field: 'userName', 'error')}">
                    <label for="userName"> <g:message
                            code="endUser.userName.label" default="User Name" />
                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="userName" value="${userInstance?.userName}" />
                </div>
                <div
                    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(model: flash?.userInstance, field: 'password', 'error')} ">
                    <label for="password"> <g:message
                            code="endUser.password.label" default="Password" />
                    </label>
                    <g:field type="password" name="password"
                        value="${userInstance?.password}" />
                </div>

            </fieldset>
```

My **Grails Version 2.4.5** and my **BootStrap.groovy** is empty

Comment: try changing the user fields to instance variables instead of static class variables

Answer (score 1):

Would your `User` class, by any chance, be sitting outside of `grails-app/domain` folder? One suggestion would be deleting your current `User` class and recreate via `grails create-domain-class`. It seems like you don't really need properties to be static or to use `@Entity`.

Comment: Agreed. I would also check that the controller is in the grails-app/controllers folder. If it is not a 'true' controller, then a hibernate session won't be automatically created for it hence would see similar error.

Comment: My class folder for USER CLASS is "grails-app\domain\com\example\ulu\User.groovy" also my CONTROLLER is at same place hiearchy. @felipecao

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @Entity from the User Domain